# Could not extract data from my Postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a problem whenever I try to run a SQL Query using Python it gives me errors in output:
=================================================**Code**=======================================

```
connexion = "host='localhost' dbname='test' user='postgres' password='aftercode'" 
pgconn = psycopg2.connect(connexion)
cur =pgconn.cursor()
data=cur.execute("SELECT client.Name FROM client").fetchall()
```

================================================**Output**=======================================

**InFailedSqlTransaction                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in**

**----> 1 data=cur.execute("SELECT client.Name FROM client").fetchall()
InFailedSqlTransaction: ERREUR:  la transaction est annulée, les commandes sont ignorées jusqu'à la fin du bloc
de la transaction**

Comment: That is a follow-up error. Try to get the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stack the methods like that. See [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html):

> execute(query, vars=None) ... The method returns None. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

So you need to to do:

```
cur.execute("SELECT client.Name FROM client")
data = cur.fetchall()

#Or

with pgconn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT client.Name FROM client")
    data = cur.fetchall()
```

Where the second form will automatically close cursor

Comment: even after i try these two Queries, i still have the same output

Comment: Does the query work in `psql`? Per @Laurenzalbe is there more to the error message? What does the Postgres log show?